# Does the Aphid Egg actually hatch?

Tags: bug-fables

The description for the Aphid Egg reads:

> An egg from a happily raised Aphid. **Make sure to eat it before it hatches**. Restores 3 HP to an ally.

Does it ever actually hatch?  If so, how long do you have to use it and what happens when it hatches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot find any documented cases of the egg hatching, so I would guess that this is just a witty description for the item.